# SKSpriteNode selector with interval

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

What's the SpriteKit equivalent of something like this?

```
[CCNode schedule:@selector(doActivate)
        interval:[[enemyData objectForKey:@"spawnTime"] floatValue]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SKAction to do this:

```
+ (SKAction *)performSelector:(SEL)selector onTarget:(id)target or 

+ (SKAction *)runBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block queue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue
```

combined with:

```
+ (SKAction *)repeatActionForever:(SKAction *)action
```

and

```
+ (SKAction *)waitForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)sec
```

for a delay between each call

Comment: And build the timer myself? Those helpers don't actually translate to the Cocos equivalent.

Comment: I edited to count for the 'timer', aka delay. This is the closest it gets for 'SpriteKit'. Your only other choice is to use a more generic iOS method for running blocks or selectors on a timer.

Comment: performSelector:afterDelay: would also work, though this is time-based not frame-based.

Answer (score 0):

Schedulers in Cocos:

```
[self schedule:@selector(doActivate:)
      interval:[[enemyData objectForKey:@"spawnTime"] floatValue]];
```

Equivalent in Spritekit using SKAction:

```
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:[[enemyData objectForKey:@"spawnTime"] floatValue]];
SKAction *performSelector = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(doActivate:) onTarget:self];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[performSelector, wait]];
SKAction *repeat   = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
[self runAction:repeat];
```